# How do I remove the CDATA tag of an XElement?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have some code that receives some XML and there is the possibility that a CDATA tag element will be present. A flag is passed into the method that states whether the CDATA tag should be present, if the flag is false, then the CDATA tag should be removed if present, how would I do this without parsing the query.Value?

```
private static void CDataTagUtility(XmlDocument catalog, XElement newData, bool addCdataTag)
{
    XElement query = newData.Element("Query").Element("CommandText");
    if (addCdataTag)
    {
        XmlCDataSection encapsulatedQuery = catalog.CreateCDataSection(query.Value);
        try
        {
            query.SetValue(encapsulatedQuery.OuterXml);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException exc) { /*Thrown due to CDATA tag already present - ignore*/ }
    }
    else //check for cdata tag - remove if present
    {
        //How do I remove the CDATA encapsulation tag???
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to remove it? In fact, why are you manipulating CDATA at all?

Comment: It is for an XML editing tool. It is not that we are manipulating CDATA, the tool is a gateway drug to manipulating CDATA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
static void RemoveCdata(XmlNode root)
{
    foreach (XmlNode n in root.ChildNodes)
    {
        if (n.NodeType == XmlNodeType.CDATA)
            root.RemoveChild(n);
        else if (n.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
            RemoveCdata(n);
    }
}

...

RemoveCdata(query);
```